# Irrationals: A Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I understand that the set of irrational numbers with multiplication does not form a group (clearly, $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=2$, so the set is not closed). But is there a proof or a counter-example that the irrationals with addition form (or do not form) a group?

Thank you!

Edit: In particular, I am wondering if the set is closed with respect to addition.

Comment: $0$ is not irrational.

Comment: $\pi+(-\pi)=0$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$0$ is not irrational. The set of irrationals is not even closed under addition:

$$(1-\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{2}=1$$

Answer (score 7):

The irrationals are the complement $\,\overline{\Bbb Q}\,$ of the subgroup $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb C$. But a complement of subgroup is not a subgroup since it does not contain the identity $\,0,\,$ nor is it closed under subtraction, not containing $\,\alpha -\alpha.$ However, one can do some group-like calculations with such complements, such as: rational + irrational = irrational. Such statements are a special case of the following *complementary* view of a subgroup.

**Theorem** $\ $ Let $\rm\,G\,$ be a nonempty subset of an abelian group $\rm\,H,\,$ with complement set $\rm\,\bar G = H\backslash G.\,$
Then $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G + \bar G\, =\, \bar G. $

**Proof**  $\ $ $\rm\,G\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,H\iff G\,$ is closed under subtraction, so, complementing

$\begin{eqnarray} & &\ \ \rm G\text{ is a subgroup of }\, H\  fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ -\ G\ \subseteq\, G\,\ \ fails\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_1\, -\ g_2 =\,\ \bar g\ \ \ for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ g_2\, +\ \bar g\ \ =\,\ g_1\  for\ some\ \ g_1,g_2\in G,\ \ \bar g\in \bar G\\
&\iff&\ \rm\ G\ +\ \bar G\ \subseteq\ \bar G\ \ fails\qquad\ {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}$

Instances of this are ubiquitous in concrete number systems, e.g. below. For many further examples see some of my [prior posts here.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+complementary+subgroup)

[image]

Comment: Are you aware if it is possible to define an operation in irrationals so it becomes a group? Or more general, given a nonempty set, is there a way to put in there an operation so it becomes a group? There's a trivial operation which does the trick, choose some $e$ in the set, then do $x\ast y=e$ for any two elements in the set.

Comment: @Leo Yes, of course, but that is of little use, versus the above, which is widely used.

Comment: Yes, its only use is mention it exist. Do you know of some other on rationals? Some interesting?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Quick question: is it known what nonalgebraic*nonalgebraic is?

Comment: @leo: the question of turning a non-empty set into a group is more complicated than that. The operation your proposed only works for sets of size $1$ or $2$, since otherwise $x$ would have as inverses $x$ itself together with at least another element of the set, which is a contradiction. You can browse this site to find how to define an operation.

Comment: @math1234567 That is the same question with other groups: Algebraic numbers are closed under multiplication, inversion and taking roots, so e.g. $\pi$ is transcendental (nonalgebraic), therefore $1/pi$ and $\pi^2$ are transcendental. But clearly $\pi \cdot 1/\pi = 1$ is algebraic, while $\pi \cdot \pi = \pi^2$ is not.

Answer (score 4):

To speak to the spirit of your question a bit: the rational numbers are a so-called *normal* subgroup of the reals (since the reals form an abelian group, and all subgroups of an abelian group are normal), so we can talk about the *quotient group* of the reals by the rationals, $\mathbb{R}\ /\ \mathbb{Q}$.  Each element of this group is a set of the form $\{r+q, q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, and the sum of two elements $s_0=\{r_0+\mathbb{Q}\}$ and $s_1=\{r_1+\mathbb{Q}\}$ is $s_0+s_1 = \{r_0+r_1+\mathbb{Q}\}$; you can convince yourself that addition of two elements doesn't depend on which representative we choose for a given element.  The identity element of this group is just the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ themselves.  This is a complicated object; for instance, any collection of representatives is a so-called *Vitali set*, and is non-measurable.  (And just building such a collection of representatives requires the Axiom of Choice!)

Comment: Is $r \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Elise for each member of the group, $r$ is a specific element of $\mathbb{R}$, whereas the $q$ in these sets ranges over all elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ - that is, each set is a shifted version of the rationals.  I'll try to make that a bit clearer in the answer when I have a good chance to edit it.