# Is the sum of a rational function and polynomial a rational function?

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

Suppose $r(x)\neq 0$ is a rational function (and not a polynomial), and $p(x)$ is a polynomial function of $x \in \mathbb R$.

> Does it follow that $r(x)+p(x)$ is a rational function (and not a polynomial)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Hint: the difference of two polynomials is again a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Suppose that $r(x)+p(x)=s(x)$ were a polynomial. Then also $r(x)=s(x)-p(x)$ would be a polynomial, hence $r(x)$ is a polynomial, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Note that the set $\rm S\,$ of  polynomials are closed under subtraction so they comprise an additive subrgoup of the additive group $\rm G$ of rational functions. Now apply the following

**Theorem**  $  $ A nonempty subset $\rm\:S\:$ of abelian group $\rm\:G\:$ 
comprises a subgroup $\rm\iff\ S\ + \ \bar S\ =\ \bar S\ $ where  $\rm\: \bar S\:$ is the complement of $\rm\:S\:$ in $\rm\:G$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652797/242) is the simple  proof. Instances of this "complementary view of a subgroup" are ubiquitous

[image]