# Subsets $A$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ such that $xy \in A \implies x \in A, $ or $y \in A$. Primality of arb. subsets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If

$$
A \subset \Bbb{Z}
$$

is such that $xy \in A \implies x \in A, $ or $y \in A$.  Then $A$ is either a prime ideal or ?

Can we describe all "prime subsets" of $\Bbb{Z}$ that aren't prime ideals in one fell swoop?

It's not just a subset closed under taking divisors, though those are counted, and so it's also not just a subset of negative prime numbers together with $\{0, -1\}$ either.

Comment: Just checking: you only mandate $xy\in A\implies x\in A\lor y\in A$ and you are not even mandating the opposite implication?

Comment: @StinkingBishop yes, that is correct

Comment: To see the relationship with primes, make the inferences bidirectional, then the complement of $A$ Is a saturated monoid, hence $A$ is a union of prime ideals. This is best viewed in terms of localization, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25740/242) in the dupe. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652797/242)  on the **complementary view of a subgroup.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the implication
$$
xy \in A \implies \big( x \in A \text{ or } y \in A \big)
$$
is equivalent to its contrapositive
$$
\big( x \notin A \text{ and } y \notin A \big) \implies xy \notin A.
$$
In other words, $A$ has the given property if and only if $\Bbb Z\setminus A$ is closed under multiplication.

In particular, there is a wide variety of examples of such sets $A$, such as:

- $A = \{-m,\dots,m\}$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$;
- $A = \{n\in\Bbb Z\colon n$ cannot be written in the form $n = 13^a2020^b\}$;
- $A = \{n\in\Bbb Z\colon n$ is not a perfect square$\}$;
- $A = \{n\in\Bbb Z\colon \text{there exists } p\mid n \text{ such that } p^p\nmid n\}$....